# openpop - Find the difference in inline image and signature image in email

Tags: c#, openpop

I begin by referring to this question that is unanswered and that is very similar to my question:

[Distinguish inline image and signature image in email using openpop.pop3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658943/distinguish-inline-image-and-signature-image-in-email-using-openpop-pop3/37563612#37563612)

I don't have enough rep to comment on the question so I have made a new one that refers to it.

I need a way to check the attachments in openpop to see if it comes from a signature (typically small logos etc.) or from a big image that has been embedded in the body of the email. SmartPhones does typically this when you add a picture as attachment in many mail apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily do this using OpenPOP.NET, but this is fairly trivial to do using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

What you can do is start with the `HtmlPreviewVisitor` sample from the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#HasAttachments) and modify it every-so-slightly to just split the attachments into 2 lists:

1. The list of actual attachments
2. The list of images used by the HTML (aka "signature images")

code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Visits a MimeMessage and splits attachments into those that are
/// referenced by the HTML body vs regular attachments.
/// </summary>
class AttachmentVisitor : MimeVisitor
{
    List<MultipartRelated> stack = new List<MultipartRelated> ();
    List<MimeEntity> attachments = new List<MimeEntity> ();
    List<MimePart> embedded = new List<MimePart> ();
    bool foundBody;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new AttachmentVisitor.
    /// </summary>
    public AttachmentVisitor ()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of attachments that were in the MimeMessage.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<MimeEntity> Attachments {
        get { return attachments; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of embedded images that were in the MimeMessage.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<MimePart> EmbeddedImages {
        get { return embedded; }
    }

    protected override void VisitMultipartAlternative (MultipartAlternative alternative)
    {
        // walk the multipart/alternative children backwards from greatest level of faithfulness to the least faithful
        for (int i = alternative.Count - 1; i >= 0 && !foundBody; i--)
            alternative[i].Accept (this);
    }

    protected override void VisitMultipartRelated (MultipartRelated related)
    {
        var root = related.Root;

        // push this multipart/related onto our stack
        stack.Add (related);

        // visit the root document
        root.Accept (this);

        // pop this multipart/related off our stack
        stack.RemoveAt (stack.Count - 1);
    }

    // look up the image based on the img src url within our multipart/related stack
    bool TryGetImage (string url, out MimePart image)
    {
        UriKind kind;
        int index;
        Uri uri;

        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (url, UriKind.Absolute))
            kind = UriKind.Absolute;
        else if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (url, UriKind.Relative))
            kind = UriKind.Relative;
        else
            kind = UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute;

        try {
            uri = new Uri (url, kind);
        } catch {
            image = null;
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = stack.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if ((index = stack[i].IndexOf (uri)) == -1)
                continue;

            image = stack[i][index] as MimePart;
            return image != null;
        }

        image = null;

        return false;
    }

    // called when an HTML tag is encountered
    void HtmlTagCallback (HtmlTagContext ctx, HtmlWriter htmlWriter)
    {
        if (ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.Image && !ctx.IsEndTag && stack.Count > 0) {
            // search for the src= attribute
            foreach (var attribute in ctx.Attributes) {
                if (attribute.Id == HtmlAttributeId.Src) {
                    MimePart image;

                    if (!TryGetImage (attribute.Value, out image))
                        continue;

                    if (!embedded.Contains (image))
                        embedded.Add (image);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void VisitTextPart (TextPart entity)
    {
        TextConverter converter;

        if (foundBody) {
            // since we've already found the body, treat this as an
            // attachment
            attachments.Add (entity);
            return;
        }

        if (entity.IsHtml) {
            converter = new HtmlToHtml {
                HtmlTagCallback = HtmlTagCallback
            };

            converter.Convert (entity.Text);
        }

        foundBody = true;
    }

    protected override void VisitTnefPart (TnefPart entity)
    {
        // extract any attachments in the MS-TNEF part
        attachments.AddRange (entity.ExtractAttachments ());
    }

    protected override void VisitMessagePart (MessagePart entity)
    {
        // treat message/rfc822 parts as attachments
        attachments.Add (entity);
    }

    protected override void VisitMimePart (MimePart entity)
    {
        // realistically, if we've gotten this far, then we can treat
        // this as an attachment even if the IsAttachment property is
        // false.
        attachments.Add (entity);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var visitor = new AttachmentVisitor ();

message.Accept (visitor);

// Now you can use visitor.Attachments and visitor.EmbeddedImages
```

An even simpler, although less error-proof, way of doing it is this:

```
var signatureImages = message.BodyParts.OfType<MimePart> ().
    Where (x => x.ContentType.IsMimeType ("image", "*") &&
           x.ContentDisposition != null &&
           x.ContentDisposition.Disposition.Equals ("inline" StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thank you jstedfast, I will test it out now!

Comment: When I try to install the MailKit NuGet I get this message: 'MailKit' already has a dependency defined for 'MimeKit'. So I tried to install MimeKit first and then MailKit again, but got the same error. Am i missing something?

Comment: Make sure you're using at least NuGet.exe version 2.8.6: https://dist.nuget.org/index.html

Comment: Note that I don't think you want to use NuGet 3.x unless you are using VS2015 and doing ASP.NET Core dev.

Comment: Thank you again Jstedfast! I had version 2.6.4, upgraded to 2.8.6 and this fixed the problem perfectly.

Comment: I have tried out some basics from MailKit and it's looking good. But when i was trying out the code you posted above i got a problem. "The name "body" does not exist in the current context". its body from "VisitMultipartAlternative". I have tried figuring it out myself but can't get the handle on it.

Comment: Thank you jstedfast! works like a charm. But i still have the question about if I can split up the embedded images from what comes from bodytext and what comes from the signature in the email? Do you understand what i want to achieve? I want the big pictures etc from body, but i don't want the small logos from the signature in the bottom of the email.

Comment: You cannot split up the images used within the body of the message and the images within the signature of the body because there's no way to tell them apart.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Do you have any suggestions on how i can on best possible way split them apart? size, bytes or something other that might help?